# How to insert single quote in html textbox without typing the single quote?

Tags: javascript, html, oracle-apex

May I know how to insert single quote in html textbox without typing the single quote on it, I had tried use HTML Character &#39 but not work ?

Eg. type M10500000003 in textbox,  error ORA-00904 : "M10500000003": invalid identifier

Eg. type 'M10500000003' in textbox, ok

```
<label for="txtName">Member Number</label><br>
<input type="text" id="txtName">
<a href="javascript:;"></a>

<a href="javascript:;" onclick="this.href='http://myIP/apex/epos.db_sql?P_SQL=select memberno,nameoncard from c19u.psm_member@c19 where memberno=' + document.getElementById('txtName').value">Check</a>
```

[image]

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: ...you just send raw SQL to your DB straight from the querystring? _yikes_

Comment: Don't put the quotes in the text box.  Put the quotes in your SQL query.  You can use `\'` to put a single quote inside a single-quoted string.  However, what happens if someone types `0; drop table c19u.psm_member@c19;` in your text box?

Comment: a *SQL injection attack* waiting to happen

Comment: @TimRoberts , ya.. you right .. \' this work.

Comment: `<a href="javascript:;" onclick="this.href='http://myIP/apex/epos.db_sql?P_SQL=select memberno,nameoncard from c19u.psm_member@c19 where memberno=\'' + document.getElementById('txtName').value + '\''">Check</a>`

Comment: one more question, it is possible change the font size from output sql query result in html page ?

Comment: Do some research then, if you can't find anything, ask a new question.

Comment: Why did you tag oracle-apex for this ? Your screenshot is an html file, not an APEX page. In oracle APEX this would be handled very differently

Answer (score 0):

add the focusout event to the input and write function to add single quotes when foucs got out from input

```
 <label for="txtName">Member Number</label><br>
 <input type="text" id="txtName" onfocusout="addSingleQuotes()">
```

In script add following function

```
function addSingleQuotes() {
    const memberNum = document.getElementById('txtName');
    if(memberNum && memberNum.value) {
        memberNum.value = memberNum.value.replace(/'/g, ''); // remove all single quotes if already appended
        memberNum.value = `'${memberNum.value}'`;
    }
}
```